# How to print key, value pair using list in java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the key and value pairs but I couldnt write it. I tried this code.For example;

```
   List<Student> list = new List();
```

I have a combobox and I want to append child as a student name, student id.

When I debug it

```
   for(int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
    combobox.appendChild(list.get(i), "");
   }
```

It shows: list.get(i)= 0. index have two values. 0. => student name
                                                 1. => studentid

How can I print

```
      combobox.appendChild(list.get(i)[0], list.get(i)[1]) something like that.
```

Comment: Doesn't the `Student` class have members `name` and `id`? For example, `list.get(i).name` and `list.get(i).id`.

Comment: Why don't use hashmap?

Comment: @ Andrew Watson Can ı convert arraylist to hashmap?because I couldnt convert it. I read from database by using list.

Comment: @ Johnny Mopp When I write this name and id is null but I set the values

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Are you using AWT, Swing, JavaFX or some other UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can only use the [] brackets to access elements of an array. To access members of a class you typically use getters.

Assuming the student class looks like this:

```
public static class Student {

    int studentId;
    String studentName;
    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
}
```

the correct way to do this would be

```
    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Student s : list) {
        combobox.appendChild(s.getStudentId(), s.getStudentName());
    }
```